# Reading files from hard drive with javascript

Tags: javascript, file-io

My application creates `.xml` files and stores them on the user's hard drive; there is a default folder that I set in the `web.xml` to store the files, let's say `D:/temp`. Now after I write the files I need to read them back with javascript, I am using a javascript library that has this function `mxUtils.load('URL of the file')` (this function returns the content of the file), the problem is that it is giving me an error `Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP`, (I now it doesn't have anything to do with the function or the library) I think the problem is that you can't read local files because of some security issues. Anyone can advise me some solution? Thanks

Comment: Yes it's a security issue. Nobody wants their browser to have unfettered access to the filesystem. Can you elaborate more about the browser being used (is it a real browser or an embedded one)? The mxUtil docs say "You may have to load chrome://global/content/contentAreaUtils.js to disable certain security restrictions in Mozilla for the open, save, saveAs and copy function."

Comment: If you are running and testing your application on a single machine then please re-verify by hitting your application from some other machine. I really doubt if you can save any file on client hard disk by configuring something in web.xml

Comment: @SpliFF What if I save the files on the server and not the user's machine, that way can I read the files?

Comment: Does it have to be actual physical files, you could just save the data in the browser with localstorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant access local filesystem using javascript.
For accessing the file using javascript , you have to upload it to a server and access it using the files url.

Comment: assume the file is on the server, how can I access it?

Comment: @ShaheMasoyan You have to give a url to the file using a protocol like HTTP or FTP.
eg: `http://yourserver.com/files/web.xml`
Then you can use `mXutils.load(url)` or `mxUtils.get(url,onload,onerror)`

Comment: the file is located on the hard drive not in my application source files (for example: it is located on D:/ ) how can I pass the url ?

Comment: @ShaheMasoyan  You cannot read local files from hard drive using javascript.

 If you want to do so you have install some plugins or something in your browser.
MxUtils documentation says that `requires an ActiveX object in IE and special privileges in Firefox.`

Comment: If so, how does the photo edit tool of the US DV lottery webpage access the images on our harddrive?  
https://www.dvlottery.state.gov/

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to expose your files via HTTP and use `mxUtils.load("http://yoursite/static/yourfile.xml")`.

Search for `static files` on [Apache HTTP Server HowTo](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/printer/apache.html). Setup Apache to serve your xml files, make sure that you can view xml file in browser and then use the same url in `mxUtils.load` call.

Comment: My files are stored on the hard drive, and can't be accessed using `http://yoursite/yourfile.xml`

Comment: What technology are you using on server side? Node.js? Asp.Net?

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you **cannot** access a file on the filesystem strictly through Javascript. You could, however, use the `input` file type to upload the file to your server and then read it:

```
<input type="file" name="myfileinput">
```

Then, you can access it via the `$_FILES` global in `PHP` - other languages also provide this functionality through other means. Please note, again, that there is absolutely no way to access a file that is on someone's filesystem with Javascript without their consent (i.e. using the file input type). That would be a huge security risk - imagine going to a page and having it wipe your whole `D:/` drive.