# searching users computer for music and video files from browser

Tags: django, python-2.7, web, dreamhost

I am currently making a website and one of the functions I want is to add a user's music and video files to their library automatically by searching for the path of them on their hard drive and adding them to a database.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/mydir"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

I know I can use this python script to search on my own server but is it possible to make it search a user's computer with the correct permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitly cannot access local filesystem of your users. It is a **security** matter.

You can read more at this related question : [Reading files from hard drive with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138001/reading-files-from-hard-drive-with-javascript)

What you can do by the way is limiting the type of file you can upload with the `accept` attribute :

```
<input id="fileSelect" type="file" accept=".txt" />
```