# Why is this not working (React without Node)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was trying to make this work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Add React in One Minute</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h2>Add React in One Minute</h2>
    <p>This page demonstrates using React with no build tooling.</p>
    <p>React is loaded as a script tag.</p>

    <!-- We will put our React component inside this div. -->
    <div id="like_button_container"></div>

    <!-- Load React. -->
    <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->
    <script src="like_button.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is the like_button.js:

```
'use strict';

const e = React.createElement;

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return e(
      'button',
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      'Like'
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

But the component (a button) doesn't appear, this is from this site:

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Please help me with this, is like it doesn't recognize the script.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, though the scripts took a while to load at my end (likely due to them being development builds). Are you seeing any console errors?

Comment: What error do you see in the console?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, here is a screenshoot of the errors: https://i.imgur.com/d4FdvEh.png

Comment: So the problem here is that you are running from a local file instead of a web server. React has a specific warning about this in the console when you actually run it (`You might need to use a local HTTP server (instead of file://`). So even though it works for most of us (works here on MacOS with your setup), it's not guaranteed to work everywhere and you should be able to explain this to your guys at work. As a last resort try toggling on "Disable cache" option in console (F12 - network - disable cache) and reload

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're running your page as a file directly from your hard drive, [which is preventing external scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20138001/reading-files-from-hard-drive-with-javascript) (like react, react-dom) from downloading. This means that `React` is never downloaded and not defined, which in turn is breaking your `like_button.js` script.

Rather that run the HTML page directly off your harddrive, try running the page through a server - if you have node installed, you can install a basic [http server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) via:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

Once that's done, run the following command from the directory containing your html page:

```
http-server
```

The console will then display the address of the server in the console. Navigating to that address in your web browser will either display the index page, or a directory listing. Navigate to the html page you are developing and you should find that everything works as expected.

#### Update

Alternativly, if you're using a chromium based browser (and are unable to install `node`), you could install this browser extension to run a local webserver on your system:

[Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb)

Once installed, you can mount and start a server (that's basically running through the browser extension) from the directory on your hard drive where your project is stored, and then navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8887` to access your page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I can't use Node.js, and from where I got this example (reactjs.org), they don't use it either. But let's suposse the are using it, is there any possibility to do this WITHOUT node.js? I mean, to link/reference scripts like that.

Comment: do you have any server software installed? apache, iis, etc?

Comment: I cannot use any of that, is some stupid rule in my work (I am a trainee and they asked to make this work), I am at a loss here, don't know what to do. Does this code work for you?

Comment: Your code works perfectly :-) - I've updated my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thany you @Dacre Denny, but I have to do it without any of that... just the html file, that's how they want it in my job :(

Comment: Ouch :\
The last option I can think of then would be to download the external scripts to your workstation, copy and paste the contents of those into your html file (contained between `<script>PASTED CODE</script>` tags. You'd need to ensure that these are pasted in the same order as listed in your current HTML file. Hope that helps?

Comment: That's how I was using it, but they want the scripts to be separated files, this is really frustating.

Comment: I don't know what I did but it worked! somehow... I'll figure it out later, now, I'm having problems adding other scripts and redering them, can someone give me an easy example? any script/component will work!

Answer (score -1):

```
import React from "react";
```

your complete code which is working properly.

```
"use strict";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const e = React.createElement;
class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return "You liked this.";
    }

    return e(
      "button",
      { onClick: () => this.setState({ liked: true }) },
      "Like"
    );
  }
}
const domContainer = document.querySelector("#like_button_container");
ReactDOM.render(e(LikeButton), domContainer);
```

Check this working properly [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-water-ute49)

Comment: @PaulWZ check this demo... which is working properly.